# RxJava - toList and still emits more than one item

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

How is following possible:

```
Observable<Data> obs = ...;
List<Data> data = obs
    .toList()
    .toObservable()
    .singleOrError() // <= this line throws the exception
    .blockingGet();
```

My code sometimes throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sequence contains more than one element!`. Shouldn't I ALWAYS get a single `List<Data>` element in my case (or null) but never multiple elements?

Comment: What is `obs`? Is it a custom `Observable`?

Comment: No. Just a lot of different rxjava2 operators wrapping a cache and a database query (and update), but no custom observable in this

Comment: You could attach [the protocol validator](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#protocol-validation) and see where it fails.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. Get this error very rarely only, so I can use this to find out the reason

Comment: Could it be that the database query return more than one element occasionally?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using `.toList()`, where the return is a Single, and then changing it to an observable, just to check whether its a single or error it out?

Why not just do this:

    Observable<Data> obs = ...;
    List<Data> data = obs
        .toList()
        .blockingGet();

Answer (score 2):

The exception should be impossible given the fact that `toList` returns a `Single` in RxJava2. So it might be caused by something upstream not properly implementing the Rx Protocol.

I suggest adding a `doOnNext` logging call between the `toObservable` and `singleOrError` to see what this potential second emission would be.

Comment: I'll add this as well and check if I get more feedback with this, additional to the suggested protocol validator

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, why are you using `.toList()`, where the return is a Single, and then changing it to an observable, just to check whether its a single or error it out?

Why not just do this:

```
Observable<Data> obs = ...;
List<Data> data = obs
    .toList()
    .blockingGet();
```

P.S: I know my answer could be wrong. Correct me if that's the case, but I wanted to post it since a comment would not allow proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.firstOrError` bcos `.singleOrError` is not expecting new items from the upstream. And fails as it should. Especially if you have list there.